# Highchart stacked column chart missing some items

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using normal stacked column Highchart for displaying two items where sometimes any of the item value might become zero.  In that case i am not getting next chart elements of that stack displayed instead only one of stack element is displayed. my sample code snippet mentioned below which might not straight forward to reproduce the issue but anyway

```
chartType : 'chart',
options : {
    chart : {
        animation : false,
        type : 'column',
        height : chart_height
    },
    credits : {
        enabled : false
    },
    legend : {
        enabled : true
    },
    title : {
        text : null
    },
    colors : ['#ED561B', '#50B432'],
    plotOptions : {
        series : {
            stacking : 'normal',
            minPointLength : 3
        }
    },
    tooltip : {
        useHTML : true
    },
    xAxis : {
        categories : categories,
    },
    yAxis : {
        title : {
            text : translations['chart.tooltip_packets'],
            useHTML : Language.isRtl() ? Highcharts.hasBidiBug : false
        },
        opposite : Language.isRtl()
    }
},
series : [{
        index : '0',
        name : 'SSS',
        data : [0, 15, 10, 20, 13, 14]
        tooltip : {
            style : {
                color : '#ED561B'
            },
            headerFormat : '',
            pointFormatter : function () {
                return '<strong>' + translations['chart.tooltip_packets'] + '</strong><br/>' + this.category + ': ' + this.y;
            }
        }
    }, {
        index : '1',
        name : 'DDD',
        data : [800, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        tooltip : {
            style : {
                color : '#50B432'
            },
            headerFormat : '',
            pointFormatter : function () {
                return '<strong>' + translations['chart.tooltip_packets'] + '</strong><br/>' + this.category + ': ' + this.y;
            }
        }
    }
]
```

My chart looks like

[image]

In chart, i have zero value SSS in the first stack and rest of the DDD have zero values but had some value of SSS there which is missing on the chart.

I don't know what is the issue here. Can any one help me?

Comment: and the data set?

Comment: see my sample data in the edited post

Comment: seems they are not missing they are just too small comparing 15, 20, 13, with 800. Set the height of the chart bigger and you will see that the chart is showing your data. Did you try to mouseover the chart to see the tooltip?

Comment: Not at all, you can see the zero value of that green strips but not 15, 20, 13 .. strange

Answer (score 1):

ok i find out the problem. turn out that you set a size for points that has value 0 with this line

```
minPointLength: 3
```

and the values with 10 15 20 are at yAxis starting at 0 but also the point with 0 value are starting at 0 and by you setting minPointLength the points with 0 value are bigger than the others and are on top of the others, so the stacked values are 0-15 and the 0 has extra size that is not stacked. did i explained myself correctly?

Comment: try setting minPointLenght to 0, or just delete that

Comment: I just introduced that as i am not getting that little SSS 0 value and all of those 0 DDD's you see in the chart. Without minPointLenght the whole chart is blank except that one long first DDD series value.

Comment: maybe you are not showing what we need to resolve your problem, i set this jsfiddle to test your code pick a look (https://jsfiddle.net/h3joa4r4/1/)

Comment: @LPZadkiel is right. This problem occurs, because the points that use `minPointLength` have their SVG rendered, but their height is not considered when generating the stack (their real value is used - `0`). It's logical when we analyze that **hypothetical example**: Let's say we have 10 series and each of them have the point with `0` y value (at the same x position). The `minPointLengt` equals to `10`. If we'd create the stack using them it will be 100px height. On this level we have the y axis tick that says the value is 1000. So the actual value of 0 looks like 1000 on the chart.